# How to resolve javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted

Tags: android, smtp, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I'm trying to send an email using an account from another server and not **Gmail**, but this exception occurs when sending.

Error:

```
02-05 16:10:37.688: W/System.err(30346): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.suprema.net.br, port: 587;
02-05 16:10:37.688: W/System.err(30346):   nested exception is:
02-05 16:10:37.688: W/System.err(30346):    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
02-05 16:10:37.688: W/System.err(30346):    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
02-05 16:10:37.688: W/System.err(30346):    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
02-05 16:10:37.688: W/System.err(30346):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
02-05 16:10:37.688: W/System.err(30346):    at com.prologica.smart_detection.Mail.Send(Mail.java:71)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.prologica.smart_detection.utils.Utilities.SendMail(Utilities.java:162)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.prologica.smart_detection.utils.Utilities.NotifyContatcts(Utilities.java:106)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.prologica.smart_detection.services.NotificationService.NotifyContacts(NotificationService.java:106)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.prologica.smart_detection.services.NotificationService.GetNotifications(NotificationService.java:79)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.prologica.smart_detection.services.NotificationService.run(NotificationService.java:61)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:374)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:598)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:560)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:1449)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1366)
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346):    ... 9 more
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb7617058: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
02-05 16:10:37.689: W/System.err(30346): error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:790 0xae73aedd:0x00000000)
02-05 16:10:37.690: W/System.err(30346):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
02-05 16:10:37.690: W/System.err(30346):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
02-05 16:10:37.690: W/System.err(30346):    ... 13 more
```

**My Method**

```
 public Boolean Send(String localFile, String subject, String body, String recipients)
 {  
    Boolean ret = false;

    try
    {  
        String user = MailSenderConfiguration.USER;
        String pass = MailSenderConfiguration.PASSWORD;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();  
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", MailSenderConfiguration.SMTP);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        //props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", MailSenderConfiguration.PORT);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", MailSenderConfiguration.PORT);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        Authenticator auth = new Autenticador(user,pass);  

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth); 

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);  
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  

         if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
            else  
                msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        //msg.setRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

        msg.setSentDate(new Date());  
        msg.setSubject(subject);  
        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
        textPart.setContent(body, "text/plain");  
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();  
        mp.addBodyPart(textPart);  
        msg.setContent(mp);  
        msg.saveChanges();  
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");  
        transport.connect(MailSenderConfiguration.SMTP, Integer.parseInt(MailSenderConfiguration.PORT), user, pass);  
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());  
        transport.close();   

        ret = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Your code includes several of the [most common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Start by fixing them.

Then follow these [JavaMail FAQ tips for debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

I can't tell from what you posted what port you're actually trying to connect to, but perhaps you're trying to make an SSL connection to a non-SSL port.  Or, you might be running into a firewall or anti-virus issue.